# Eclipse is not running after Installing Lombok

Tags: eclipse, lombok

Eclipse is not running after Installing Lombok. I have downloaded the latest version 18.x.x from their website.

Removing the line '-javaagent:D:\eclipse\lombok.jar' that was automatically added to eclipse.ini during installation solves the issue.
What I am missing since I cannot install lombok.jar?

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:115)
    at org.eclipse
```

Comment: is there a 'caused by' line in there?

Comment: @rzwitserloot not understood?, can you eleborate what you mean by 'line in there'.

Comment: surely your stack trace in the logs don't at the characters "at org.eclipse". Keep reading; at some point, I expect: "Caused by: ..." - the error 'Error starting module' sounds like there's an error that caused this error, and unless someone at eclipse messed up and bugged up the code, the cause should ALSO be listed, below this error. It would be more useful than this error.

Comment: @rzwitserloot the cause  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Great start. Now update the question with that and the entire stacktrace and that might get to something that is debuggable.

Comment: @rzwitserloot its what I can add due to limitation
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.createProtectionDomain(ModuleClassLoader.java:359)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.createClassPathEntry(ModuleClassLoader.java:260)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.createClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:
 org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.addStandardClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:195)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.addClassPathEntry(ClasspathManager.java:190)

Comment: Ok finally solved my issue.
I changed  heap size  to 6 GB in eclipse.ini . 
-Xms6000m
-Xmx6000m

Earlier it was following.
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m